# My buttons only appear when I click them or my cursor is over them

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jbutton, layer

First of all, sorry for my English!

I am creating a videogame as a beginner, and I have four buttons, but I dont know why I can only see them when i put my mouse over them.

Maybe is because I have a thread?

I will try to upload the code and classes!!

Thank you very very much!!!

```
package Launcher;
import Character.CharacterSet;
import Character.CharacterFabric;
import Character.CharSelection;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        WindowPanel winP = new WindowPanel();
        winP.myWindowPanel();

        CharSelection charSelection = new CharSelection();
        charSelection.myCharSelection();



    }


}
```

```
package Launcher;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import javax.swing.*;

import  Character.Player;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements  Runnable{

    //Window settings variables
    KeyHandler KH = new KeyHandler();
    final int originalTileSize = 16; //16x16px
    final int scale = 3;
    final int tileSize = originalTileSize * scale; //48x48px
    final int maxScreenCol = 16; //Tiles in a column
    final int maxScreenRow = 12; //Tiles in a row
    final int maxScreenWidth = tileSize * maxScreenCol;
    final int maxScreenHeight = tileSize * maxScreenRow;


    Thread gameThread;

    Player player = new Player(this, KH);
    int framesPS = 60;


    //Player pos
    int playerX = 100;
    int playerY = 100;
    int playerSpeed = 4;
    public GamePanel(){

        this.setVisible(false);

        //Window Settings with variable implementation
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(maxScreenWidth, maxScreenHeight));
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.addKeyListener(KH);
        this.setFocusable(true);

        //////////7
        JButton exit = new JButton();
        JButton moreSize = new JButton();
        JButton lessSize = new JButton();

        exit.setSize(30, 30);
        moreSize.setSize(30, 30);
        lessSize.setSize(30, 30);


        //exit.setVisible(true);
        exit.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        this.add(exit);
        ///////
        //optionSel = "Archer";

        JButton butW = new JButton("^");
        butW.setSize(500, 500);
        butW.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        this.add(butW);
        butW.setVisible(true);
        butW.revalidate();
        butW.repaint();

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.repaint();
        this.revalidate();



        }


    public void startGameThread(){
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();


    }

    public void update(){
        //System.out.println(playerY);

        //System.out.println(upP);
        if(KH.upPressed){
            playerY -= playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(KH.downPressed == true){
            playerY += playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(KH.leftPressed == true){
            playerX -= playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(KH.rightPressed){
            playerX += playerSpeed;
        }

    }

    /*public void run(){

        double drawInterval = 1000000000/framesPS; //0.0166 seconds
        double nextDrawTime = System.nanoTime() + drawInterval;

        while(gameThread != null){



            //long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            //1.Update
            update();
            //2Draw screen info
            repaint();



            try {
                double remainingTime = nextDrawTime -System.nanoTime();
                remainingTime = remainingTime/1000000;

                if(remainingTime < 0){
                    remainingTime = 0;
                }

                Thread.sleep((long)remainingTime);

                nextDrawTime += drawInterval;

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }




    }*/


    public void run(){

        double drawInterval = 1000000000/framesPS;
        double delta = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime;
        long timer = 0;
        int drawCount = 0;

        while(gameThread != null){

            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (currentTime - lastTime)/drawInterval;
            timer += (currentTime-lastTime);
            lastTime = currentTime;
            if (delta >= 1){
                update();
                repaint();
                delta--;
                drawCount++;
            }
            if(timer >= 1000000000){
                System.out.println("System FPS= "+drawCount);
                drawCount = 0;
                timer = 0;
            }




        }
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        //System.out.println("painting");

        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2.fillRect(playerX, playerY, tileSize, tileSize);





        g2.dispose();

    }



}
```

```
package Launcher;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class WindowPanel {

    //public static String optionSel;
    public boolean startThread;
    public void myWindowPanel(){

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        //Window Creation

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setTitle("My Game");
        window.setLocation(0, 0);//No le indica un lugar especifico donde salir, por lo que sale en el medio






        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        window.add(gamePanel);

        ///
        JButton butW = new JButton("^");
        butW.setSize(100, 100);
        butW.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        gamePanel.add(butW);
        butW.setVisible(true);

        butW.revalidate();
        butW.repaint();

        ///


        window.pack();





        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        gamePanel.startGameThread();




    }


}
```

I´m trying to see the buttons :C

Comment: Can you also post your `KeyHandler` class? Right now, the example you gave us does not compile because it cannot find that `KeyHandler` class.

Comment: 1) Don't use the `dispose()` method on a Graphics object that you don't create. You should NOT dispose() the graphics object passed to the paintComponent() method. 2) Swing is double buffered by default 3) there is no need for all the revalidate() and repaint() and setVisible() statements in your constructor. Swing components are visible by default, except for top level containers like JFrame and JDialog. 4) Using the setSize() method does nothing. By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout. So the layout manager will set the size of the button to be its preferred size.

Comment: If you need more help the post a proper [mre]. Your question is about displaying the buttons. So all the logic related to the KeyListeners and game loop is irrelevant to the stated problem. First the the buttons visible then add back in that logic. This is always the way you should code. That is write a little code and test. Then add more code and test. When/if it stops working you know what you just changed. Don't try to write the entire application before testing.

Comment: Sorry for all! Im not used to do this so I dont know what to upload! Thank you all for your help!!!

I created a drive link with all my game classes:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12HI9fXSNhfFY9_1XomcYT-3_9sdibcLc?usp=sharing

Comment: @camickr wondering where all these recent graphic.dispose (in paintComponent) come from? Some severely broken tutorial/youtube video you might be aware of?

Comment: @kleopatra, I'm not aware of any common source of the problem.

Comment: @camickr - could have been as you are a permanent expert here while I'm just lurking again since some weeks, thanks :)